# Cookies not working properly in my application

Tags: php, cookies

I have used this code to set cookies

```
 {
   setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365);
 }
```

In a sub folder it displays the value in $_cookies['username2'] but when I call it on root it does not print any value

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the setcookie so that it will be available to the whole domain.

```
setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
```

[Manual for setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)